# Environmentally friendly or DIY dog waste digester solution?

Tags: waste, pets

Last year, I made a backyard dog poop composter (like [this one](https://pethaus.com.au/blogs/news/13879355-diy-pet-poo-composter)). This way we keep dog poop and bags out of the landfill.

The problem is, it's filling up faster than than it's breaking down. I've been using [Doggie Dooley waste tablets](https://ht-pet.com/shop/ols/products/waste-terminator-tablets) to support the right kind of microbes, but they don't seem very effective, I can only get them online, and they aren't really cheap (since it seems like the only solution is to use more of them).

Since what I have is essentially a miniature septic system, is there something else I could use? either an environmentally friendly off-the-shelf product that my grocery store or hardware store might have, or a DIY solution?

Comment: I assume you or someone else in the household is already picking up the Fido Nuggets by some means & placing them in the composter. Why not by-pass the composter & place them in the household toilet & flush them. Very inexpensive.

Comment: @Fred that would result in increased water usage and, I suspect, loud protestations from my family :)

Comment: You can keep the poo in a dish and put them to the household toilet just before using the flush; I do this with my cat litter (a special one which goes to toilets)